# Table per Hierarchy w/ Foreign Keys - Best Practices

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql, database-design

I am trying to figure out how best to model the following scenario in SQL. I am using C# and Entity Framework.

I have multiple different entities that need files. Here is some pseudo code defining scenario:

```
CategoryPage {
    string Name;
    Content Content;
    CategoryImage Image;
}

StaticContentPage {
    string Name;
    Content Content;
    BannerImage Banner;
}

ProductPage {
    string Name;
    Content Content;
    ProductImage[] Images;
}

Content {
    string Value;
    ContentFile[] Files;
}

File {
    FileData Data;
}

CategoryImage : File {
    CategoryPage Category;
}

BannerImage : File {
    StaticContentPage Page;
}

ProductImage : File {
    ProductPage Product;
    int SortOrder;
    bool IsPrimary;
}

ContentFile : File {
    Content Content;
}

FileData {
    byte[] Data;
}
```

Content is broken out as a separate entity because I want to have more advanced features like change tracking/history and want it to work the same for any content section. Additional files needed by any content section (images, PDF download, etc.) can be uploaded to that content section.

---

To my understanding, the foreign key should live in the entity that depends on the other. All of the above entities with file/images don't require them (`CategoryPage` is perfectly valid without an image, a `ProductPage` might not have any images added to it, a `Content` section might not need any additional files), so I figured the FK should be on the `File` entity. So I did a Table Per Hierarchy configuration with a discriminator:

```
Files
-----
Id
Discriminator
FileDataId
CategoryPageId
StaticPageId
ProductPageId
SortOrder
IsPrimary
ContentId
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? On the one hand, I like it because when a page is deleted, it'll cascade down to the files and delete them without any additional domain logic to catch that. On the other hand, I am worried that it is adding unnecessary complexity and could lead to performance issues.

I've also had issues with multiple cascade paths the TSQL doesn't like (I didn't show it above, but I have the `Content` entities broken out in a similar way to the `File` entities, so when you delete the Category page, it'll cascade to both the File table and the Content table, and then from the Content table to the File table again).

Would it be better to just have a generic File entity, keep the FK on the consumer's side (ie. the `CategoryPage`, `StaticContentPage`, `ProductPage`, and `Content` entities), and handle the delete logic in my domain layer? Or would it be better to have separate tables for each file type? Or is there another way I am not thinking of?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to roll your own content management system. Have you done any research into existing products? Doing it yourself is a _lot_ of work.

Comment: No CMS I've looked at met our needs. This isn't meant to be a generic CMS, but to help manage a specific site with an existing product data model. I could technically get away with offloading the static content management to an existing CMS and only doing product data management in this tool, but that'd be confusing to the people that will end up using it; easier for them if everything is together, organized in a way that makes sense to them.